# Why is the Gödel sentence accepted as true?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

The Gödel sentence G means "G and ¬G are independent of Peano arithmetic". Couldn't it be false? Couldn't there be actually a way to get to ¬G just from Peano axioms?

Comment: Exactly; the Gödel sentence $G$ is *undecidable* in (first-order) Peano arithmetic, i.e. neither $\mathsf {PA} \vdash G$ nor $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \lnot G$

Comment: But $G$ is an arithmetical formula; thus, it expresses a fact about natural numbers that it must hold or not. But the construction of $G$ is such that $G$ - when read through" the encoding -  "reads" as a formula that asserts that $G$ itself is **underivable** in $\mathsf {PA}$, and so it is. Thus, $G$ is TRUE in the "common sense" view of the term.

Comment: How are you so sure? Maybe there is a very long proof within PA that gets to ¬.

Comment: No, **if** $\mathsf {PA}$ is consistent, there is no proof of $G$ in $\mathsf {PA}$. How can we be sure? Exactly as about Pythagoras Theorem: w ehave proved it.

Comment: If I'm correct, Con(PA) => G is derived from the acceptance that G is true and not backwards. Please, tell me if I'm wrong. Then, it might follow that ¬G is reacheable within PA and if a proof is found, Con(PA) => ¬G.

Comment: The Gödel sentence $G$ is a sentence of PA asserting that $G$ is not provable in PA. That is not the same as "$G$ and $\lnot G$ are independent of PA" (which is clearly true of $\lnot G$ if it is true of $G$).

Comment: We could if PA is incoherent or inconsistent. Any incoherent theory can prove anything. This is very unlikely though. Edward Nelson thought he found a proof but it was shown to be wrong.

Comment: @RobArthan and Mauro. I can see my mistake now. Have a nice day.

Comment: Let me see if the question with G = "G is not provable in PA" makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As RobArthan said in his comment, the Gödel sentence  is a sentence of PA asserting that  is not provable in PA. That is not the same as " and ¬ are independent of PA".

Comment: But that wouldn't be a Gödel sentence. Thanks anyway. I will be thinking about a sentence like that.

Comment: I made an edit removing that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, the sentence in your OP isn't actually a Godel sentence. However, we can still ask what its status is with repect to (dis)provability in $\mathsf{PA}$. In particular, given its "Godelish flavor," it may seem plausible that it too should be independent of $\mathsf{PA}$. The situation is in fact rather surprising:

Suppose $A$ is a sentence of the type in the OP. Within $\mathsf{PA}$, we can argue that if $A$ were $\mathsf{PA}$-disprovable then $A$ would be false; that is, $\mathsf{PA}\vdash Prov_{\mathsf{PA}}(\neg A)\rightarrow \neg A$. This is a direct consequence of the OP-property of $A$.

Now we apply [**Lob's theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem) to $\neg A$: since $\mathsf{PA}$ proves "If $\neg A$ is $\mathsf{PA}$-provable, then it is true," we in fact get an outright $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of $\neg A$! Snappily:

> "I am $\mathsf{PA}$-undecidable" is $\mathsf{PA}$-**disprovable**.

(A more common application of Lob's theorem which may be easier to think about is that "I am $\mathsf{PA}$-provable" is $\mathsf{PA}$-**provable**.) See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834781/why-intuitively-is-lobs-theorem-true) for some discussion of the intuition behind Lob's theorem; the general topic of [provability logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/) may be of interest as well.